# Why is ssh sometimes blocked by TP-Link WR841N?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ssh

I have a TP-Link WR841N wireless router.   When I connect both my MacBook Pro and a Raspberry Pi to the router over WiFi, I typically cannot ssh from the MacBook Pro to the Raspberry Pi:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro-5:dyoung dyoung$ ssh pi@192.168.0.120
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.120 port 22: Operation timed out
```

However, if I reboot the TP-Link router and wait for the computers to reconnect, then this works fine (for a few hours):

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro-5:dyoung dyoung$ ssh pi@192.168.0.120
pi@192.168.0.120's password: 
Linux RaspberryPi 4.19.57-v7+ #1244 SMP Thu Jul 4 18:45:25 BST 2019 armv7l
```

After some period of time, I can no longer ssh anymore with the same timeout.

When I cannot connect via SSH, both the MacBook Pro and the RaspberryPi have internet access just fine.  I can reach google through a web browser using a keyboard and monitor on both devices.  Both devices have IP addresses on the same 192.168.0.x range.

If I reboot the Pi or the MacBook to try to correct the problem, nothing changes.  Rebooting the router is the only thing aI have found that helps.

What could possibly cause this?

I tried updating to the latest firmware on the TP-Link WR841N, and I have restored factory settings.  The only things I have customized are the Wireless SSID and Key, and to set an IP reservation for the Raspberry Pi so I know it is at 192.168.0.120.  The default security settings have:

```
Firewall
  Enable Spi Firewall [x]
VPN
  PPTP Pass-through:  [x] Enable [ ] Disable
  L2TP Pass-through:  [x] Enable [ ] Disable
  IPSec Pass-through: [x] Enable [ ] Disable

ALG
  FTP ALG:  [x] Enable [ ] Disable
  TFTP ALG: [x] Enable [ ] Disable
  H323 ALG: [x] Enable [ ] Disable
  SIP ALG:  [x] Enable [ ] Disable
  RTSP ALG: [x] Enable [ ] Disable
```

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue on the router... check the system log (or firewall log if accessible). If that router offers a way to view the firewall log output, and you're unable to trace the issue, create a firewall rule to explicitly allowed traffic on the Pi's SSH server port between both IP and MAC of both devices _(firewall rules are processed chronologically)_